# Ruby on Rails 3.2.3 not creating foreign keys after rake db:migrate (MySQL db)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :comments

end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

end
```

Then I ran: rake db:migrate. I don't get a "user_id" field/column in my Comment table. I also tried: rake db:drop, rake db:create and rake db:migrate. I'm probably missing a step, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the migration.

when you create the comments model by

```
rails generate model comment
```

rails also generate the migration file in your_appication_root/db/migrate/.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
       t.references :user
       t.text, :content
       t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

the important row for you is

```
t.references :user
```

or you can define it directly by

```
t.integer :user_id
#but this do not add the db index
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add those to a migration.

You can define if like this in a new migration

```
add_column :comments, :user_id, :int
```

or change your migration and use the helper

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  ...
  t.references :user
end
```